# How to fix too many values to unpack in python when i am trying to send multiple columns from an excel file to function?

Tags: python, excel, google-custom-search

I am trying to send two columns from columns read from excel file to a google custom search function .I am getting error in the loop:
    import os
    print(os.getcwd())

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('contactibility_sample.xlsx')
#print the column names

from googleapiclient.discovery import build


my_api_key = ""
my_cse_id = ""



def google_search(search_term, orTerms, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, orTerms=college, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']


values = df['Contact_name'].values
college_name = df['College_name'].values

for name,college in values,college_name:
    results = google_search(name, college, my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=5)
    for result in results:
        print result[u'formattedUrl']
```

**Error**

```
runfile('C:/Users/abc/untitled14.py', wdir='C:/Users/abc')
C:\Users\abc
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-8f88ce8c799d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/abc/untitled14.py', wdir='C:/Users/abc')

  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/abc/untitled14.py", line 33, in <module>
    for name,college in values,college_name:

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

My excel file is:

```
Contact_name    Mobile_number College_name  loan_id Age
Subham Biswas   9169999996    R.A.I.T       87867   23
Ketaki Joshi    9898989821    IBS           65432   24
Prashant Roy    9090909090    VIT           22342   28
Roshni singh    9191919191    IBS           23331   24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to `zip` together `values` and `college_name` before iterating over them.

```
for name,college in zip(values, college_name):
    ...
```